# problem parsing JSON Strings

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

```
var records = JSON.parse(JsonString);

for(var x=0;x<records.result.length;x++)
{
  var record = records.result[x];
  ht_text+="<b><p>"+(x+1)+" "
    +record.EMPID+" "
    +record.LOCNAME+" "
    +record.DEPTNAME+"  "
    +record.CUSTNAME
    +"<br/><br/><div class='slide'>"
    +record.REPORT
    +"</div></p></b><br/>";
}
```

The above code works fine when the JsonString contains an array of entities but fails for  single entity. result is not identified as an array!
Whats wrong with it?

http://pastebin.com/hgyWw5hd

Answer (score 2):

result **is not an array**. Do you see any square brackets in your JSON? no you do not. it does not contain any arrays.

```
{
  "result": {
    "ID": "30",
    "EMPID": "1210308550",
    "CUSTID": "1003",
    "STATUS": "2",
    "DATEREPORTED": "1273234502",
    "REPORT": "this is one more report!",
    "NAME": "Sandeep Savarla",
    "CUSTNAME": "Collateral",
    "LOCID": "4",
    "LOCNAME": "Vijayawada",
    "DEPTNAME": "SALES"
  }
}
```

Can you show me what your "valid" json looks like when the function above works?

Comment: It works for that because that **is** an array.  If it's not an array, you can't loop over it.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure it's an array before you iterate

```
if ( 'undefined' == typeof records.result.length )
{
  records.result = [records.result];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looping through `records.result` as if it were an array.
Since it isn't an array, your code does not work.

This simplest solution is to force it into an array, like this:

```
var array = 'length' in records.result ? records.result : [ records.result ];

for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    var record = array[x];
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `result` is an object, not an array. Wrap it's value in square brackets to make it an array:

```
{
  "result": [{
    "ID": "30",
    "EMPID": "1210308550",
    "CUSTID": "1003",
    "STATUS": "2",
    "DATEREPORTED": "1273234502",
    "REPORT": "this is one more report!",
    "NAME": "Sandeep Savarla",
    "CUSTNAME": "Collateral",
    "LOCID": "4",
    "LOCNAME": "Vijayawada",
    "DEPTNAME": "SALES"
  }]
}
```